# React Native MaterialTabs Items array

Tags: react-native

We have a Json Data that products' information is stored in it.Every product has a Type and we want to  push the Types in an array completely.I'm using MaterialTabs for showing the Types.
I introduced a function for returning the Types like below:

```
    setCategorys(){
    var typelist=[];
    for(var i=0;i<this.state.shop_Products.length;i++){
      var typelist1 = typelist.push(this.state.shop_Products[i].type);
    }
    return typelist1;
  }
```

MaterialTabs has to be like this: ["type1","type2"]
I also  introduced a MaterialTabs  like below:

```
        <MaterialTabs
          items={[this.setCategorys()]}
          selectedIndex={this.state.selectedTab}
          onChange={this.setTab.bind(this)}
          barColor='white'
          indicatorColor="#ff1a00"
          activeTextColor="#ff1a00"
          inactiveTextColor= "#000"
        />
```

But I got error[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example given on https://github.com/iRoachie/react-native-material-tabs works on my end. From the error, it looks like one of the items in the array is undefined.